# Merge multiple CSV files that share 2 columns into one unique data frame

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, merge

I have multiple CSV files (like 200) in a folder that I want to merge them into one unique dataframe. For example, each file has 3 columns, of which 2 are common in all the files (`Country` and `Year`), the third column is different in each file.

For example, one file has the following columns:

```
Country  Year    X 
----------------------
Mexico   2015    10
Spain    2014    6
```

And other file can be like this:

```
Country  Year    A
--------------------
Mexico   2015    90
Spain    2014    67
USA      2020    8
```

I can read this files and merge them with the following code:

```
x = pd.read_csv("x.csv")
a = pd.read_csv("a.csv")
df = pd.merge(a, x, how="left", left_on=["country", "year"], 
                right_on=["country", "year"], indicator=False)
```

And this result in the output that I want, like this:

```
Country  Year    A    X
-------------------------
Mexico   2015    90   10
Spain    2014    67   6
USA      2020    8
```

However, my problem is to do the previously process with each file, there are more than 200, I want to know if I can use a loop (or other method) in order to read the files and merge them  into a unique dataframe.

Thank you very much, I hope I was clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use glob like this:

```
import glob
print(glob.glob("/home/folder/*.csv"))
```

This gives all your files in a list : `['/home/folder/file1.csv', '/home/folder/file2.csv', .... ]`

Now, you can just iterate over this list : `from 1->end, keeping 0 as your base`, and do `pd.read_csv()` and `pd.merge()` - it should be sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# update this to path that contains your .csv's
path = '.' 

# get files that end with csv in path
dir_list = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if file.endswith('.csv')]

# initiate empty list
df_list = []
```

```
# simple for loop with Try, Except that passes on iterations that throw errors when trying to 'read_csv' your files
for file in dir_list:
    try:
        # append to df_list and set your indices to match across your df's for later pd.concat to work
        df_list.append(pd.read_csv(file).set_index(['Country', 'Year']))
    except: # change this depending on whatever Errors pd.read_csv() throws
        pass
```

```
concatted = pd.concat(df_list)
```